# C - Getting user input for a char * in a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct with a char pointer member. 
I Cannot figure out how to read in user input and store it inside the pointer.
Here is a snippit of my code, any help is appreciated

**BusRoute.c**

```
void setBusRouteInfo(){
    for(int i=unusedE; i<10; i++){
        printf("Entry %d: Route Number: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&(route[i].busRouteNumber));

        printf("Starting Location: ");
        //Get user input for starting location

    }//end for
}//end function
```

**BusRoute.h**

```
struct busRoute {
    int busRouteNumber; //successfully storing user input
    char *startingLocation; //trying to store user input here
    char *endingLocation;
    char driverName[36];
}route[10];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to allocate memory to it. So do something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    route[i].startingLocation = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
}
```

Now you can use the adress in startingLocation to pass it like this:

```
scanf("%s", route[i].startingLocation)
```

Be aware that you have to know beforehand how large the input will be (in this example it's 1 KB).